# Формирование URL DLE (alt_name)

Tags: php

Существует движок DLE.  В Бд УРЛ страницы хранится в ячейке "alt_name". Мне нужно положить в ячейку значение из переменной. 
Сейчас URL выглядит так:

> http://torrent2/o-skripte/62-2-post.html

Мне нужно

> http://torrent2/o-skripte/62-mortal-combat-13.html

Но когда я кладу в alt_name значение из переменной (mortal combat 13) - страница не открывается.
Я вручную заменяю пробелы на тире в админке - все работает. Когда делаю в БД - ничего не работает.

Пробовал вообще убрать пробелы в БД в ячейке alt_name:

> mortalcombat13

Тогда все идеально работает.

Подскажите, в чем ошибка?

Пробовал замены на %20 и  urlencode - не пашет все равно.

Answer (score 1):

С тире так и не нашел ответа.

Нашел другой выход - заменить пробелы нижним подчеркиванием.

```
$altname = mb_strtolower($title);
$altname = str_replace(' ', '_', $altname);
$altname = strval($altname);
```

Вот так все работает на 100%. Сейчас оптимизирую.
Этот код работает при условии, что изначально тайтл имеет англоязычную кодировку.